# Rest service content type is showing as text/xml?

Tags: c#, wcf, json.net

I am working on a project where i need to consume existing soap service in rest service. Return type of soap services is dataset which i need to return in json format.

I am able to returned data in json format but issue is i am getting content type as text/xml instead of application/json. Data is returning back in JSON format in soap envelop which i don't need as i need data should be in application/json content type.

I have created json wrapper where request and response types are in json format as per below code.

```
 [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetDetail")]
        [OperationContract]
        DataSet GetDetail(string property, int code);
```

Below is my web.config

```
 <endpoint name="TutorialJSOn" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IJsonWrapper"></endpoint>
```

I am using windows application where i am consuming this JSON wrapper.

Please help how could i get data in application/json content type instead of text/xml

Comment: Why do you use wcf for rest service? Just use Web.Api instead.

Comment: I need to use wcf only in this case as need to consume wcf soap services through that which is internal for our product.

Comment: You can consume wcf service but return data with web api. Both of them is compatible each other.

Comment: Can't it possible without web api to come into picture where i can get data in application/json format?